# delete method in web api not work

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api

i'm using web api with asp.net web forms 4.5 and i have problem in delete method .
that not work but other methods work good.
please help .
this my delete method:

```
 [HttpDelete]
    public void DeleteConversation(long id)
    {
        if (_repository.UserConvers(long.Parse(User.Identity.GetUserId())).All(a => a.Id != id))
            return;
        var item = _repository.Get(id);

        if (item == null)
        {
            throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
        }
        _repository.Remove(id);
    }
```

and this is my web config :

```
 <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
  <remove name="FormsAuthenticationModule" />
  <remove name="WebDAVModule"/>
</modules>
<handlers>
  <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
  <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
  <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
  <add name="CKUpload" path="/Handlers/CKUpload.ashx" verb="*" type="UI.Handlers.CKUpload,UI" />
  <add path="Captcha.ashx" verb="*" name="Captcha" type="UI.Handlers.Captcha,UI" />
  <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
</handlers>
```

Comment: What is the `_repository`? Is it your `DbContext` object?

Comment: When you say *it doesn't work* do you get any error at all or it's just that nothing get deleted ?

Comment: _repository is an object of repository layer.

Comment: I don't get any error like 404 or 405

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that inside your delete method in _repository class that you are calling SaveChanges(). Nothing wrong with your Method and you should be able to access it by issuing HTTP Delete to uri "/api/{controllerName}/45541"

Comment: thanks for reply .I request with ajax this uri but that not work

Comment: If you are using Route Attributes you should attribute your delete method with [Route(id)]